# Welcome page (and login) to be index? or a separate welcome page? HTML5

Tags: css, html

Confusing question to put in the title, but when creating a website where someone has to log in first is that typically called a welcome page. 
Which is more common?
To have the index redirect to a login page automatically or for the index page to be the "Welcome: Login: Username[   ] Password [   ] Submit"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends entirely on what flow best suits your website/app.

"More common" is pretty meaningless as a generalisation. If you're not fussed, do a quick audit of a handful of similar websites to the one you're planning and do what they do. :)

Answer (score 0):

Most at time it is recommended that your index page should have your login form somewhere just like Facebook, twitter .. because
1) most at time Google and some search motors do not like redirection that much. So if you want your website to be well positioned in Google, you better avoid a lot of redirection 
2) Redirecting the user takes some seconds and nowadays people prefer not to waste time by using application that are using ajax and avoid redirection.